# How to add prefix or suffix to range of cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, cells, range

I have cell A in excel full of images name without the extension I want to add ".jpg" as a suffix to these ranges of cells however I need to skip non text cells by not adding anything. Any help to achieve that?

```
A             B
-----  >>>>  ----
image1       image1.jpg
image2       image2.jpg

image4       image4.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and errors I found the solution it might be not efficient enough but it's helpful so far

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1);A1&".jpg")
```

You can replace ".jpg" with anything you'd like to add to the end.

Same for Prefix

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1);"prefix"&A1)
```

Please note the blank cells will be filled with FALSE to remove that use notepadd++ and replace all FALSE with \n to keep lines static

Comment: =IF(ISTEXT(A1),"prefix"&A1,"")

Answer (score 1):

You can replace "kg" with anything you'd like to add to the end.

Same for Prefix

```
=IF(ISBLANK(J3), "", J3&" KG" )
```